# iPhone icons and Mono

Tags: mono, xamarin.ios, monodevelop, application-loader

Today i've deployed my application and i'm ready to publish it on the Apple Store.
I've set **Spotlight & Settings Icons** as follow

- Image 29x29 (image icon29x29.png)
- Retina Display (58x58) (image icon58x58.png)
- iPad Compatibility (50x50) (image icon50x50.png)

and **App icons**

- Ipad Compatibility 72x72 (image icon72x72.png)

I'm having the following problem when i'm trying to upload binary with Application Loader. 
For each of the images is

> iPhone/iPod Touch: icon29x29.png: icon dimensions (29x29) don't meet
>   the size requirements. The icon file must be 57x57 pixels in .png
>   format

(just change image name and pixels reference).

I am sure that my images are the **right size** otherwise monodevelop not allow me to insert them if they were the precise size.

My images are in **Images folder** of my projects. I've tried to set those as **Content** or **iTunesArtwork** and **Copy in Output Directory** but nothing changed.

My system configuration is

- MonoDevelop 3.0.4.7
- MonoTouch 6.0.0.0
- Mono 2.10.9

Must i deploy my application without those images?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a **solution** to my problem.

If files are **under directory** Images\ in my project give me this kind of **error**.

**Instead** if files are at same **solution level** all work fine and images are loaded perfectly.

Maybe it's a bug in MonoDevelop (Info.plist file generation)

Answer (score 0):

I would think this could be related to not filling out *all* the icons (there should be a 57, 100, 114, 144).

In the `Info.plist` file, these images are stored in an array, so I'm not sure how Apple decides what do to if all of them are not present.

Comment: In Info.plist there are references about those files...maybe are not binded how Apple want.